# How to deal with date change in a django query

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model of a kind of todo list that, amongst others, contains fields for the weekday and the time the task has to be completed.

Let's say I have a night shift. Some tasks have to be performed before midnight, others after. Now I want to list tasks that, for example, have to be completed on a Friday in the todo list of the shift starting Thursday.

One possibility is to reflect that on the model side, i.e., to enter tasks that should be finished Mon-Fri morning with weekdays Sun-Thu. Then the query is rather straightforward, but one has to be careful when entering new tasks. Is there also a way to enter the "correct" weekdays and deal with the date change on the query side? I saw approaches with `union` and `itertools.chain`, but then I'm limited in further operations on the queryset (like another `filter` or `annotate`).

Is there another way?

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's easier than I thought. ```final_queryset = first_qs | second_qs``` seems to do the trick. I can also do additional operations on the queryset. In that case I'm curious what's the difference to ```union(first_qs, second_qs)```, which does not allow additional filters etc?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```first_qs.union(second_qs)```